# How do you securely clear a TEdit's text in C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I need to securely clear a `TEdit` control that has sensitive information so the process memory won't contain it (I'm not worried about the paging file at this time).

I've tried directly accessing the `String` to set the current length to spaces (using `_wmemset()`) which I then would use to update the `TEdit` control.  By using the same size string of spaces, I would suppose the `TEdit` control would use its existing buffer to overwrite.

However, I can't even get the `String` buffer to directly update.

I have seen examples that use `UniqueString(EditControl->Text)` but end up with errors like:

> candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument

plus two others about:

> no known conversion of the other string types

If I use `data()` or `c_str()`, it apparently is changing a copy and not the string because if I print out `EditControl->Text` I get the same unmodifed string.

So my first question is, how do I clear the buffer used in a `String` to ensure the sensitive data is no longer in memory.

The second question is, how do I end up clearing the `TEdit` control as well?

Comment: `TEdit` stores its text contents in `FText` private field that is defined in `TControl` class from which `TEdit` is derived from (at least in Delphi it is). So you would probably need to use RTTI for gaining direct access to the mentioned field. Once you get direct access to the mentioned field safely overwriting its contents will be easy.

Comment: @SilverWarior the text is *also* copied into the internal buffer of the underlying Win32 `EDIT` control. So, while clearing `FText` may be possible with some work, overwriting the Win32 buffer is not. At least, not by default. If you were to use `TMemo` instead (or at least give the `TEdit` window the `EM_MULTILINE` flag), you could then use `EM_SETHANDLE` to take over buffer management of the text, then you would have your own buffer which you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the accessing the `Text` property of `TEdit` is always temporary and used to send/retrieve data from the control directly.

So for sensitive data you'd want to avoid using the `Text` property and instead use some old school Win32 `SetWindowText()/GetWindowText()` i.e. `::SetWindowText(EditControl->Handle, TCharBufWithString);`

Then you can have control over your own buffers.

Comment: The issue is only with *reading* the `Text` property, not *setting* it. `SetWindowText(EditControl->Handle, TCharBufWithString);` is identical to `EditControl->Text = TCharBufWithString;` So, if the former works for you, then so will the latter, in which case something as simple as this should work: `EditControl->Text = StringOfChar(_D(' '), EditControl->GetTextLen());`